# largest palindrome number (it's the same number if you read it from left to right or right to left)

Tags: c++, xcode

The task is to find the largest palindrome number made from the product of two 3-digit numbers but I can't understand where i made a mistake.

I made a loop where I get all the possible products of two 3-digit numbers; then I transform the product in an array so that I can verify that is a palindrome number and finally if it is bigger than the last palindrome number, I save it to the variable max_palindrome

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int number_of_digits(int num){
    int digit = 0;
    while(num > 0){
        digit++;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return digit;
}

int main() {
    int max_palindrome = 0;
    for(int a = 100; a < 1000; a++){

        for(int b = 100; b < 1000; b++){

            int product = a * b;
            int digits = number_of_digits(product);

//          transform number in a vector
            int vector_product[digits];
            int temporary_num = product;
            for(int c = digits-1; c >= 0; c--){
                vector_product[c] = temporary_num % 10;
                temporary_num /= 10;
            }

//          verifying that the number is a palindrome
            int d = digits-1;
            bool palindrome = true;
            for(int e = 0; e < digits; e++){
                if(vector_product[e] != vector_product[d]){
                    palindrome = false;
                    break;
                }
                d--;
            }

            if(palindrome && max_palindrome < a){
                std::cout<<max_palindrome<<std::endl;
                max_palindrome = product;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout<<"The biggest palindrome number from a product of two 3-        digits numbers is "<<max_palindrome<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: C++ does not support VLA

Comment: but I am not using vla, I'm first checking the length of the number and then I'm creating an array of that length

Comment: the question is why it doesn't work

Comment: Yes you do - `int vector_product[digits];`

Comment: FWIW, `std::string forward{to_string(product)}; std::string backward{forward.rbegin(), forward.rend()};` will allow you to check if `forward == backward` and if it does you know you have a palindrome.

Comment: @BONANDRINICARLO The "variable" in "variable length array" does not mean _"it changes after you created it"_ but _"it is unknown at compile time"_. Also, please be more specific than "it doesn't work" when asking questions. How do you know it doesn't work? Is there an error? If so, please show the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is wrong:

```
if(palindrome && max_palindrome < a){
```

should be instead:

```
if(palindrome && max_palindrome < product){
```

your program may be much simpler if you just convert number to string (could be slightly slower, but you already waste CPU time by doing loop over number twice).